# Terraform on gcloud: serviceaccounts is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "serviceaccounts"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google, terraform

I am trying to write terraform code for bootstrapping a GKE cluster (with RBAC) on Google Cloud.
The GKE cluster successfully created, but I want to create a service account as wel which I can reuse for my later `kubernetes` provider configuration.
This means that I need to use the `kubernetes` provider in my **submodule** to temporarily create  the `kubernetes_service_account` needed for the rest of my terraform code.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s_autopilot_cluster" { ... }

provider kubernetes {
    alias = "k8s_gcloud_temp"
    cluster_ca_certificate  = base64decode(google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
    host                    = google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.endpoint
    client_certificate      = base64decode(google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
    client_key              = base64decode(google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)
}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "terraform_k8s_sa" {
    provider = kubernetes.k8s_gcloud_temp
    metadata {
        namespace = "kube-system"
        name = "terraform-k8s-sa"
    }

  automount_service_account_token = false
}
```

So my cluster is created successfully, but the creation of my `kubernetes_service_account` always fails with `Error: serviceaccounts is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"`.

Any idea why I cannot use `master_auth` and what I should use instead?

Comment: I've used the example you've included (the difference is that I used standard and not auto-pilot cluster) and stumbled upon same issue. I've fixed it with adding: `data "google_client_config" "provider" {}`, removing the `client_certificate` and `client_key` and adding the: `token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token`. Please let me know if it solves your question. More reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/using_gke_with_terraform

Comment: Funny enough I ended up with the same fix. Thanks for stumbling against the same issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data "google_client_config" "provider" {}
provider kubernetes {
    alias = "k8s_gcloud_temp"
    cluster_ca_certificate  = base64decode(google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
    host                    = google_container_cluster.k8s_autopilot_cluster.endpoint
    token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
}
```

Comment: For me the relevant part of the answer above was setting `token` using the data from `google_client_config` (e.g., local `gcloud` settings).